# Map Doesn't Load when I try to set the height dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I load the map on my page, it loads fine with this code:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width: calc(100% - 2px); height: 800px;"></div>
```

However, when I try to load it this way, it won't load and I don't understand why.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width: calc(100% - 2px); height: calc(100% - 2px);"></div>
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't loading? Are they're any recommended alternatives so I can get the height of the map to dynamically fit my div? It doesn't necessarily need to have two pixels of room. Thanks!

Comment: what is calc supposed to be doing here? does this get picked up by javascript some how? in any event, it probably doesn't help that you are attempting to subtract pixels from percentage. Try obtaining the height of the parent element in px first, and subtracting the 2px from that

Answer (score 1):

When you set a percentage based height, the parent's height also needs to be defined. A height of `calc(100% - 2px)` is equal to `0` if the parent's height is `0`. Given that this worked with a fixed `px` based height, you simply need to set the parent's height in order for it to work.

Assuming that the direct parent's height is defined with a percentage based value, use the following:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZX2R/) demonstrating this.

Alternatively, if the element is wrapped with another element, use a fixed `px` based height. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZX2R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try giving it a min-height, I don't think the map will render if it doesn't have a height.

```
#googleMap
{
  min-height:10px;
}
```